# Node.js- convert array of strings to objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

We export database to csv and than restore it using the csv files. When reading the csv file, lines like

```
0,"SIMry",0,"ROOT",false,true,null
```

get converted to array of strings.

```
 ["0","SIMry","0","ROOT","false","true","null"]
```

`Int, NULL, Boolean` all loose their meanings. I want the output to be

```
[0,"SIMry",0,"ROOT",false,true,null]
```

I am using `fast-csv` node library.

Comment: So you're saying that the earliest access you have to this is when it's *already* become an array of strings in that `["0","SIMry","0","ROOT","false","true","null"]` format? If so, it's too late. You need to intevene *sooner*. (That also seems like *really* bizarre behavior for a CSV library.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The library actually provides a string stream and calls JSON.parse on the string stream in the object mode. I don't mind reading the file line by line.

Answer (score -1):

Use JSON.parse. For example the following code

```
var a= ["0","SIMry",0,"ROOT",false,true,null];
var a_string = JSON.stringify(a); // This is what your library does
var a_json_var = JSON.parse(a_string); // This is how you compensate

console.log (JSON.stringify(a_json_var));
if (a_json_var[5]){console.log ("boolean");}
```

will print

```
["0","SIMry",0,"ROOT",false,true,null]
boolean
```

Comment: The OP's quoted text, `["0","SIMry","0","ROOT","false","true","null"]`, will **not** magically turn into numbers, booleans, and `null` with the above.

Comment: It would not. Where it was a number it would still be a number. Same for string. Should look carefully before downvoting

Comment: Again: The text the OP listed will not magically get interpreted by `JSON.parse`. Try parsing what they *actually said they have*. By the time they have that, it's too late, the information has been lost. (I looked plenty close at the answer. You don't know who downvoted it. *Assuming* you know based on who engaged with you is going to be wrong more often than right. Complaining about it is *always* wrong. Instead, consider *why* and pay attention to feedback.)

Comment: Yes. Once everything is string it will remain a string.